# Soot:Invalid option -android-jars

Tags: soot

While I wanted to run soot using the option -android-jars from command line, I got the error "Invalid option". I downloaded the soot source code (sootall-2.5.0) from https://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/soot_download.html, and I built the project in eclipse successfully.

I also downloaded soot-master and soot-develop source code. I saw this two have the option "-android-jars" but when I built project, there were too many errors... So I failed again.

How can I solve this problem? I am very very fresh new about Soot. I hope somebody can help me. thx~

Comment: What errors did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

The version you are using is too old. The command-line option was not yet present in Soot 2.5.0.

Comment: Yes, so I built the develop version. But when I run the project with arguments '-cp . -pp Test'  in eclipse, it comes to an error 'couldn't find class: Test'. I put the Test.java in Soot/bin/ directory. Is that right?

Comment: In this case Test should be in your "current working directory" - whichever you have configured in your Eclipse launch config.